# Convert integer to String Spring Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
public ModelAndView showUserAppsByID(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
   String emIDConvert= Integer.toString(id);

   // ...
}
```

This `Controller` format works but is not the same as what I expected.

Example:

- `id=3`
- `id=43`

My expectation:

- `id=0003`
- `id=0043`

That main I want to format Integer to String varchar(4).

Comment: There’s no data type in Java as varchar. What is the problem you’re having?

Comment: I want to format int id to string but example id=3 but i want to format to id=0003 or id=43 format to id=0043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has nothing like `varchar`, just a `String` of a variable length or a character array with a fixed length (`char[4]`). Practically, everybody uses `String`, unless the character array is specifically required (for example passwords).

You can use a simple static method [`String#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) to introduce the leading zeroes.

```java
 String emIDConvert = String.format("%04d", id));
```

Demo:

```java
String.format("%04d", 3));      // returns 0003
String.format("%04d", 34));     // returns 0034
String.format("%04d", 345));    // returns 0345
String.format("%04d", 3456));   // returns 3456
String.format("%04d", 34567));  // returns 34567
```

This method uses the `java.util.Formatter`, and the JavaDoc links to its details [`here`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#detail).

Comment: nice format thank somuch is work for me